# Undefined directive in PhpStorm

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using PhpStorm with Angular.
If I declare directive like this:

```
angular.module('myDir', [])
    .directive('myDir', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, controller) {

            }
        }
    }]);
```

PhpStorm regonizes that HTML tag and works great (ex. ctrl+lmb=go to declaration).

But when I switch to that code (which is preferred by https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) PhpStorm gives me unknown HTML tag message.

```
angular.module('myDir', [])
    .directive('myDir', myDir);

function myDir() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, controller) {

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: This topic is probably better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: it's a bug - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14092#tab=Linked%20Issues

Answer (score 1):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14092 -- accordingly to the status this issue has been fixed.

Fix will be in available next PhpStorm version -- must be build #140.1763 or newer (quite likely it will be PhpStorm v9).